# How to determine which room a player is in?

Tags: algorithm, game-physics, collision, game-development, godot

I am working on a 2D platforming video game. The rooms are divided into areas, which are essentially intangible hitboxes. The camera is bounded by these hitboxes, and will not show what is in the next room until the player transitions into a new one.

If the player walks from one room to another, the camera pans to the new room. Panning the camera pauses the physics engine to ensure the player cannot break the game or die while the camera is in it's animation.

My problem exists in the fact that the player doesn't belong to a single room at a time since the player's hitbox is 2D. When the player moves between rooms, for a short period of time, the hitbox overlaps two rooms at once.

This means, that if I pan the camera when the player enters a new room, the player can partially enter the new room (while still remaining in the old room), then go back into the old room, which doesn't pan the camera back because they never technically entered the old room. How could they have entered it? They never left it!

This also means, that if I pan the camera upon the player leaving a room, the player can partially enter a new room, then leave the new room that they never fully entered. This means that the camera pans to the same room that it was already in (this plays a weird animation, and pauses the physics engine).

How can I determine what room the camera should pan to?

I have access to:

1. When the player enters a room, and which room.
2. When the player exits a room, and which room.
3. All rooms, and the variables of all rooms.

```
func _on_room_area_2d_body_entered(body): # body enters room
    if body.is_in_group("junko"): # is this the player?
        player_inside = true
        junko.pan_camera(self) # pan the camera

func _on_room_area_2d_body_exited(body): # body exits room
    if body.is_in_group("junko"): # is this the player?
        player_inside = false
```

[image: Here is a screenshot which shows the player's hitbox, along with the two hitboxes of adjacent rooms.]

Comment: If you are going to allow transitions, I think you need a more complex model, or you subdivide the sprites in real-time so that they are always in one room. Are the hitboxes all much smaller then all rooms?

Comment: Yes. The player is only 8x12 pixels, and the rooms are typically several hundred pixels in width and height.

I was previously using an additional hitbox of a single pixel as the "room hitbox" for the player, which allows the player to exist in only one room at once, but I'd prefer to use only one hitbox.

Comment: I wonder if an anchor at the centre of the hitbox allowing the sprites to definite be in one room or the other, just overlapping, would work for your game? The hitbox would be fairly useless when detecting collisions with objects that are near to the sides. However, I've never used godot; it's likely this is not the best approach.

Comment: How about an small area of size `player.width -1` between rooms that belongs to no room ? That way when the player enter the new room, it has already totaly left the precedent room, and the player can only be in one room at a time

Comment: @AloisChristen Instead of deflating the rooms, can simply use player's center (x,y) instead of the entire hitbox to determine the room. Just saying :)

Comment: @YakovGalka this is not possible. I am only able to know when the player's hitbox overlaps with the rooms, and when his hitbox stops overlapping with the rooms. The player's center position is irrelevant.

Comment: @tygutowski "not possible"? may require writing some code; might be hard with that engine of yours; but that is definitely possible.

Comment: @YakovGalka yes, its possible, but its less efficient than using the built-in nodes that the engine supplies. It is also more complicated than the method I was using originally. There are hundreds of ways I could approach this problem, but I wanted the most efficient / least complicated method.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the rooms are big, it does not mean they have to keep track of what is inside of them. Instead, the character can keep track of inside of which rooms it is.

If you want to detect areas, you need an area. So make an area child of your player character… Which I'll call `locator`. Then set the `locator` up to detect the areas that make up the rooms. That means that `locator` must be monitoring, and the rooms must be `monitorable`. And also the collision layer of the rooms must overlap the collision mask the `locator`.

Then you can use `area_entered` and `area_exited` (notice these signals are called `area_*` not `body_*`).

You might find it easier to call `get_overlapping_areas` on the `detector` in `_physics_process` and then from the result pick the rooms.

```
for entry in $locator.get_overlapping_areas():
    prints(entry)
```

*Then perhaps only pan the camera when there is only one room and it is not the one where the camera is currently at, or some similar rule.*

---

In fact, you don't need a detector. You can do what "Yakov Galka" suggested in the comments and ask Godot what areas are in a particular point.

You do that with [`intersect_point`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physics2ddirectspacestate.html#class-physics2ddirectspacestate-method-intersect-point):

```
var result:Array = get_world().direct_space_state.intersect_point(
    global_position,
    32,
    [],
    2147483647,
    false,
    true
)
```

And that returns an `Array` with the results. So you can iterate like this:

```
for entry in result:
    prints(entry.collider)
```

To explain the parameters:

- First you pass the point coordinates `global_position`.
- Second you pass how many result you want at most (`32` in this case).
- Then you pass an array with elements you want to exclude (none in this case: `[]`).
- Then the collision mask (`2147483647` is all the bits)
- Then if you want bodies (no, so `false`)
- And finally if you want areas (yes, so `true`).

Please notice that even though this is only checking a single point, it does not guarantee you have a single result (you can have multiple if the areas overlap).